# Running node.js modules on webpage

Tags: node.js, express, pug, javascript

```
extend layout
block content

script.
  var monitor = require("os-monitor");

  monitor.start();

  monitor.start({
     delay: 3000
     , freeman: 1000000000
     , uptime: 1000000
     , critical1: 0.7
     , critical5: 0.7
     , critical15: 0.7
     , silent: false
     , stream: false
     , immediate: false
  });
  monitor.on('monitor',function(event) {
     console.log(event.type, 'This event always happens on each monitor cycle!');
  });
  monitor.on('loadavg1',function(event) {
     console.log(event.type, 'Load average is exceptionally high!');
  });
  monitor.on('freemem',function(event) {
     console.log(event.type, 'Free memory is very low!');
  });
  monitor.throttle('loadavg5',function(event) {
  },monitor,minutes(5));
  monitor.config({
     freemem: 0.3
  });
  monitor.stop();
  monitor.isRunning();
  monitor.start({stream:true}).pipe(process.stdout);



block side bar
  .widget
     h1 Widget
     p
     | Sed ccccc rhoncus ut
     | eleifvvvv in nulla enim.
     p
     | Vivambbbbbbbbbbbbt molestie
     | vebula.
```

```js
var express = require('express');
var stylus = require('stylus');
var nib = require('nib');

var app = express();

function compile(str, path) {
  return stylus(str)
 .set('filename', path)
 .use(nib())
}
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(stylus.middleware({
  src: __dirname + '/public',
  compile: compile
}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
 title: 'Home'
  })
});
app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Server start http://localhost:3000');
});
```

I made a simple website and server as node.js with jade.
I want website to show process status, not only in a terminal, so I found some modules (npm os-monitor, cpu-usage) to check my process stat. But I do not know how to run them on web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably better off just using something like [`socket.io`](http://socket.io/) to communicate the data from the server to the browser. Use the `os-monitor` or whatever other modules you want on the server (in your `app.js`) and then broadcast or individually send the data to browser clients.